# (Python) Coding style parentheses in ifs, loops, etc

Tags: python, coding-style, parentheses

Just your personal preference, which do you prefer?

```
if filename in filesAndFoldersList:
    while a != "TEST":
        a = input("Input: ")
```

Or

```
if(filename in filesAndFoldersList):
    while(a != "TEST"):
        a = input("Input: ")
```

Either one works, so this is just personal preference I think. Second one is more similar to Java/C++. But which you do prefer and why?

Comment: I would do neither. You are writing python  not java or c++ so why would you use parens? If a was not defined you would also get an error

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. So please avoid questions like that.

Comment: The first line of code can also look like this: `if(((filename in filesAndFoldersList))):`. That might give you the hint that adding useless parentheses is not a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

You should *never* use parentheses directly after the keyword of a statement, as you do in your second style. You are confusing the reader by making it look like they are functions. All you are doing is group the expression in parentheses, Python will ignore these and all you have achieved is the removal of the space after the keyword.

Neither can you use the style with *all* compound statements; you cannot use the style with a `for` loop or a `with` statement that includes the `as <target>` clause.

The [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) makes no mention of the second (parenthesized) style, at all; it makes the assumption that no-one would use it.

Note that this is separate from [using parentheses around long *expressions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements), where you use `(...)` around the `if` condition expression if it is otherwise too long to fit on a single line. In such a situation you want to put a space between the opening `(` and the `if` keyword:

```
if (
    this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing or
    (more_conditions and such_things)
):
    do_something()
```

Comment: Did you mean no mention of the second style?

Comment: @Tt: yes, the style where you use parentheses everywhere.

Comment: Hey, you're right. Parentheses didn't work for a for loop. Didn't know that. Guess you have to use the first style. Also how do I delete a post in SO?

Comment: @Tt: The C-syntax languages just use the parenthesis as delimiter. Otherwise, if the statement was not a block statement, it could not determine where the expression might end for some cases. If a _block_ was **required**, they were obsolete. There's lots of other languages, which also do not require this, for instance the whole Pascal-group (Pascal, Modula, Oberon, Ada, Dephi, etc.). That because they differentiate between expressions and statements much stronger.

Comment: @Tt: you cannot delete the post; you received an answer so now the question and answer together are a collective work, licensed under the CC Wiki license. As such you cannot unilaterally delete it without destroying the combined work.

Comment: "The Python Style Guide makes no mention of the second..." [uhhh](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements)?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar: that section deals with solutions to long expressions that have to cross multiple lines. I can see that my statements in this answer sound contractionary, so I'll see what I can do to edit.