# Hi. What is the difference between placing the conditions of the if statement in brackets and without? Is it due to preference and readability?

Tags: python

```
def biggerNumber(number1, number2):
  if(number1 > number2):
    print(number1, "is bigger")
  else:
    print(number2, "is bigger")

biggerNumber (18,332)
```

and this

```
def biggerNumber(number1, number2):
  if number1 > number2:
    print(number1, "is bigger")
  else:
    print(number2, "is bigger")

biggerNumber (18,332)
```

Comment: The parentheses are superfluous. You might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Comment: The only reason to use parens would be if you need to group different parts of a complex expression.  For a case like this they're just visual noise.

Comment: It's for unreadability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coding style parentheses in ifs, loops, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30549554/2745495)

Comment: @GinoMempin yes this seems to be the same topic, I did try to search for a similar post, I am quite new to the language, thanks for pointing this out.